# Tsql AND(&) confusing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Select Cast(656878503183 as bigint)  & Cast(8 as bigint)

Result
8
```

Can someone help me with this. How is the result coming as 8? I am a bit lost in this .

Last digit of `656878503183` may be `3`

```
0011 AND
1000
-----
0000
```

which is 0

Comment: Note that in T-SQL `AND` and `&` are not equivalent operators. The `&` is a [bitwise operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx), and `AND` is a [logical operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189773.aspx).

Comment: When something this basic is "wrong" assume that you made a mistake, rather than assuming that the language/tool/etc is misbehaving.  Go back and triple check all of your calculations and assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In binary, the larger value is represented as 1001100011110001000000101000010100001111, and 8 as 1000. If you notice, the 4th bit from the right is 1 for both. Therefore, the `bitwise and` operation evaluates to 1 only for that bit, and 0 for all others. Therefore the result of applying `bitwise and` to the 2 numbers will end up with 0000.... 1000 which is again 8.

```
1001100011110001000000101000010100001111
0000000000000000000000000000000000001000
----------------------------------------
0000000000000000000000000000000000001000
```

Note: I used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx) tool to perform the conversion, didn't actually evaluate the thing myself, so I would suggest that you double check that the conversion is correct just to be sure.

Comment: Extra credit for showing the AND operation for the entire width of the numbers.

Comment: Why didn't you do the conversion yourself!!!???  By the way Windows calculator would do the conversion just fine.

Comment: Don't worry about @shree.pat18 's conversion. I just did it with Ruby and got exatcly the same result he did with TSQL.   Let's remove the TSQL tag, as your question applies to any language.

Comment: You can also test it via PowerShell. `[int64]656878503183 -bAnd [int64]8`

Comment: I think I made the mistake in finding the number's binary. I went for Hex I think.. Anywway great thanks to Shree..